# Can a function in $\mathcal{W}^{1,2}((a,b); \mathbb{R})$ be unbounded?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I  want to see an example of unbounded functions in the space $\mathcal{W}^{1,2}((a,b); \mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, $W^{1,2}(a,b)$ can be embedded into $C[a,b]$. (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality). So every function in $W^{1,2}(a,b)$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So an open interval $(a,b)$ for $\mathcal{W}^{1,2}((a,b);\mathbb{R})$ does not change the fact that every function in $\mathcal{W}^{1,2}((a,b);\mathbb{R})$ is bounded. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, it's right if the interval is bounded.